# Find active serial ports in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: bash, serial-port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can i find which **serial-port** is the active one in *Windows Subsystem for Linux*? I know about the [added support in ***WSL***](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/14/serial-support-on-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/) for using the `/dev/ttyS`, but which of these ports are active?

The issue I'm trying to solve is I have a device which keep switching comport, because of the internal chip that reconnects it self on a new port. I want to create a bash script that finds the active serial-ports.

*Regular linux commands like:* `dmesg | grep tty` ***does not work.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a solution combining both ***Powershell*** and ***WSL***.

### 1.Create a Powershell script,
comports.ps1:

```
$DeadComport = 3
$COMportList = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames() 

if ($COMportList.Count -cgt 2) {
    Write-Output "Too many com-ports connnected! " 
    Write-Host -NoNewline "Com-ports found:" $COMportList.Count
   
}else{
     ForEach ($COMport in $COMportList) { 
        $temp = new-object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $COMport 
        $portNr = $temp.PortName.SubString(3)
        if ($portNr -eq $DeadComport){
            continue   
        }
        Write-Output $portNr
        $temp.Dispose() 
    }
}
```

*- You can debug this code in **PowerShell ISE** and adjust it to meet your preference.*

### 2.Create a bash script in WSL,
comscript.sh:

Preferably in the `home/your-username/bin` folder, that makes the bash-script globally executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Active com-port"
powershell.exe -File "c:\your-folder\comports.ps1"
```

Now you can just call ***comscript.sh*** and it will output the active comport, if more then one device is found it will throw an error message.

*Be aware that I'm filtering out com-port 3, since it's always there and active on my computer.*

Comment: Great answer! Works fantastically. I adapted it in a couple of ways:

1. Removed the `if ($COMportList.Count -cgt 2) {` block, as I didn't think 6 is "too many"
2. Modified output to give the corresponding `/dev/ttyS*` ports with `Write-Output "/dev/ttyS$portNr"`

Answer (score 1):

On the latest WSL 2 `dmesg | grep tty` will work just fine.

Getting the devices to work is a pain though.

```
ADMIN PS> wsl --update

PS> winget install --interactive --exact dorssel.usbipd-win

WSL> sudo apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-77-generic hwdata
WSL> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/usbip usbip /usr/lib/linux-tools/5.4.0-77-generic/usbip 20

# Open a new ADMIN PS
PS> usbipd wsl list
PS> usbipd wsl attach --busid <busid>

WSL> lsusb 
WSL> ll /dev/ttyUSB*
PS> usbipd wsl detach --busid <busid> # when you're done with your device
```